# How to set attribute programmatically

Tags: java, android, attr

I have an attribute

```
<attr name="ColorMain" format="reference|color" />
```

If I need to set it as colors in the xml file then I write the following

```
android:textColor="?attr/ColorText"
```

How do I do this programmatically?

Tried doing like this but it doesn't work like that

```
et_name.setTextColor(R.attr.ColorTextNotActive);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Theme theme = context.getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.ColorTextNotActive, typedValue, true);
@ColorInt int color = typedValue.data;
et_name.setTextColor(color);
```